# Run an AppleScript from Swift

Tags: applescript, xcode, swift

I'm trying to return a value from AppleScript to Swift (in XCode). If I do this simple code it works:

```
let myAppleScript = """
        return "hello world"
        """
    var error: NSDictionary?
    if let scriptObject = NSAppleScript(source: myAppleScript) {
        let output: NSAppleEventDescriptor = scriptObject.executeAndReturnError(&error)
        print(output.stringValue)
    }
```

and if I run display dialog I get the alert on the screen, though there are issues with dismissing it. But if I run this code:

```
let myAppleScript = """
        set appList to my getAppList()
        return appList
        on getAppList()
            tell application "System Events"
                return name of every application process as list
            end tell
        end getAppList
        """
    var error: NSDictionary?
    if let scriptObject = NSAppleScript(source: myAppleScript) {
        let output: NSAppleEventDescriptor = scriptObject.executeAndReturnError(&error)
        print(output.stringValue)
    }
```

It returns nil. I am trying to port an AppleScript I wrote to XCode to make it more dynamic and give it a UI.

Am I doing something wrong or is this just not possible?

Comment: The script works just fine, but note that the result is not a _string_, but a _list_.

Comment: That makes sense, but what property of NSAppleEventDescriptor is the list returned under? print(output.data) presented 0 bytes.

Comment: You need to do something like [iterate through NSAppleEventDescriptor and extract the strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55551772/).

Comment: I found some stuff about coercing to an AEList. I got that to work with a hard coded list but when I tried it on the return the array was empty. So more digging on that end of the problem.

Comment: Using the answers from the linked topic, I got the expected results using your sample script in a playground.  Are you doing something else that is not generating a list of strings?